# What is the difference between char and nchar datatype when installing oracle 11g with unicode char set option?

Tags: oracle11g

I install oracle 11g with unicode char set option. And I found that I can insert unicode character into CHAR datatype column. So my question is that:
what is the difference between CHAR and NCHAR datatype when installing oracle 11g with unicode option ?

Comment: any comment would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 5):

There are two main differences.

1. The default for the length semantic.  By default

   `CHAR(30) != NCHAR(30)`  but  `CHAR(30 CHAR) = NCHAR(30)`.

   The default length semantic (as specified by the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter) is used for CHAR but not for NCHAR.  The default value for this parameter is byte. The length of NCHAR is always in characters.  This is important because NCHAR(30) will always hold 30 unicode characters - as will CHAR(30 CHAR) - but CHAR(30) will only hold 30 bytes by default which may or may not equal 30 unicode characters.
2. AL32UTF8 (the database characterset unicode default) and AL16UTF8 (the NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET default) are not equivalent.  Both are variable length unicode character sets but store characters differently so storage requirements between the two vary with the former using 1, 2, 3 and sometimes 4 bytes per character and the later 2 and sometimes 4 bytes per character).  Your mileage will vary depending on the characters you store.

   Additionally NCHAR support is limited in many client applications and some Oracle components so if you use AL32UTF8 for the database character set, Oracle's advice is to just stick to CHAR and not use NCHAR at all.

Comment: There is no `AL16UTF8`, there is `AL16UTF16` or mentioned `AL32UTF8`. There is also `UTF8` which differs slightly from `AL32UTF8`. `AL16UTF16` is completely different from them.